# undefined reference to pthread create error

Tags: 20.04

When working with POSIX threads in a C program, I found "undefined reference to pthread create" error.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

void *myThreadFun(void *vargp)
{ 
  sleep(1); 
  printf("Printing Sample \n"); 
  return NULL;
}
```

Although my gcc and g++ compilers are working pretty fine.
Moreover, I am compiling this code using this command:

```
gcc test.c -o test
```

Comment: @steeldriver, edited and provided all the necessary details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error “undefined reference to pthread create” is caused when the pthread header is not included in the program file. Ensure that the header file is included properly as follows.

```
#include <pthread.h>
```

The other cause is that pthread is not used in the command line while compiling the code. To include the thread while compilation, use the syntax.

```
gcc -pthread -o threads <cprogram>.c
```

Found this solution on [this post](https://itslinuxfoss.com/undefined-reference-pthread-create/)